# Retrieve a value from input do some calculation and display in a paragraph

Tags: javascript

Hi i am new to javascript

i want to retrieve the value of a input field and calculate for Celsius and display in a paragraph tag.

```
function toCelsius() {
var f = document.getElementById("someno").value;
alert(f)
     return (5/9) * (f-32);

}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = toCelsius();
```

Comment: Hi, you're also new to Stack Overflow. We're not a code-writing service. Please read the help section and learn how to ask a proper question. Your "question" doesn't even have a question mark in it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only follow this example... it's pure JS. When you change the value in the input and focus out you can see the result in the div with id "final"

```js
function toCelsius(f,destiny) {
    var result = (f-32)*5/9;
 document.getElementById(destiny).innerHTML='<p>'+result+'</p>';
}
```

```html
<label for="farenheit">
 <input name="farenheit" id="farenheit" type="text" onchange="toCelsius(this.value,'final')" value="0">
</label>
<div id="final">

</div>
```